# Transfer data from FocusableIframe to block

Tags: wordpress, plugins, block, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to make a selection in an iframe at the editor and transferring the selection to the element where it will be displayed at the saved page. How do I get the data from the iFrame back to the registered block ?

How do I store these data ?

My current not working code:

```js
blocks.registerBlockType('XXX/XX-block', {
      stringToUpdate: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      edit: function(props) {
        return (el(components.FocusableIframe, {
              src: "https:///....my-iframe.php"
            },
          }
        }),
      save: function(props) {
        return (el('div', {
          className: 'stringToUpdate'
        }, 'stringToUpdate'))
      }
```

Comment: This is not a comment, edit your question to include the properly formatted code